# Putting sentences in the array as element in Javascript, Is this possible?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I'm trying to change sentences with following Image when I clicked 'previous' or 'next'.
First of all, can I put sentences in the array as element like this?

```
var content = new Array("Big sale!","Children's Day-Special Sale",
"Buy here","Click here to sign up");
```

HTML

```
<table>
  <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td><span onclick="previousImg()">pre</span></td>
    <td><img id="slideImage" src="img/promotion1.jpg"></td>
    <td><span onclick="nextImg()">next</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3"><span id="information">information of the Image</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Javascript

```
  var images =  new Array("img/promotion1.jpg", "img/promotion2.png",
              "img/promotion3.jpg", "img/promotion4.jpg");


  var content = new Array("Big sale!","Children's Day-Special Sale",
                "Buy here","Click here to sign up");

  var image = document.getElementById("slideImage");
  var string = document.getElementById("information");
  var imgNumber=1;
  var numberOfImg = images.length;

  function previousImg(){
      if(imgNumber > 1){
        imgNumber--;
        }
      else{
        imgNumber = numberOfImg;
      }
      var preText = content[imgNumber-1];
    image.src = images[imgNumber-1];
    string.innerHTML = preText;
    }

  function nextImg(){
    if(imgNumber < numberOfImg){
      imgNumber++;
      }
    else{
      imgNumber = 1;
      }
      var nextText = content[imgNumber-1];
    image.src = images[imgNumber-1];
    string.innerHTML = nextText;
    }
```

I want "Big Sale!" come up with img/promotion1.jpg, and "Children's-" change on the same time with img/promotion2.png.

Help me...Thank you!

Comment: Unrelated to your question but if you plan on allowing the blind to be able to use your site then you need to use either the `<a>` tag or the `<button>` tag for your navigation instead of a `<span>` tag. Screen readers work better that way. Be aware that you will need additional CSS to get the correct tag to look like you want it.

Comment: @Intervalia Thank you for your kind comment. I will fix it right away :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have declared variable 'image' twice. Rename the array of images.

Comment: @WonGyeong Did that fix it? If so, was it just a typo in copying?

Comment: @Michal G Thank you for your comment! Now I fixed it

Answer (score 2):

I took the liberty of rewriting your code to include some best practices.

First the code:

CSS

```
.nav-button {
  background: none;
  border: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

HTML

```
<table>
  <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td><button class="nav-button" onclick="previousImg()">pre</button></td>
    <td><img id="slideImage"></td>
    <td><button class="nav-button" onclick="nextImg()">next</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3"><span id="information"></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

JavaScript

```
var items = [
  {img: "img/promotion1.jpg", text: "Big sale!"},
  {img: "img/promotion2.png", text: "Children's Day-Special Sale"},
  {img: "img/promotion3.jpg", text: "Buy here"},
  {img: "img/promotion4.jpg", text: "Click here to sign up"}
];

var imageEl = document.getElementById("slideImage");
var infoEl = document.getElementById("information");
var itemNumber = 0;
var numberOfItems = items.length;

function setInfo() {
  var item = items[itemNumber];
  imageEl.src = item.img;
  infoEl.innerHTML = item.text;
}

function previousImg() {
  itemNumber--;
  if (itemNumber < 0) {
    itemNumber = numberOfItems-1;
  }
  setInfo();
}

function nextImg(){
  itemNumber++;
  if(itemNumber === numberOfItems) {
    itemNumber = 0;
  }
  setInfo();
}

setInfo();
```

Now the explanation:

I combined your image information and text information into an array of objects. This allows you to keep your data in chuncks instead of in different arrays.

I converted from `new Array()` to use using `[]` and `{}` for `new Object()`.

I change your `<span>` with the `onclick` to `<button>` tags to better conform with Screen readers to better support the blind. I also added some CSS to make the `<button>`s not look like buttons. It is up to you how you want them to look.

I broke out the code to set the image and text into a single function and call it from the other functions to reduce replicated code. And I call that function once to set the original image and text into the page.

I changed the logic in your prev and next functions to be simpler.

Comment: Wow Thank you so much! But I have one more question. I moved javascript codes to js file, and liked it to HTML. I wrote right 'src' but I can only see 'pre' and 'next' buttons. Your code works great when I put it all together. Can you please help me with this too? @Intervalia

Comment: Make sure the JS file is loaded after the `<table>`. Put it as the last child tag of the `<body>` tag. If not then the call to `document.getElementById` will fail because the elements won't be defined yet.